# Can I get a percentage of the phones that would support a J2ME Midlet application given all the JSR's it uses?

Tags: java, java-me

Can I get somehow(from a database or other source) a percentage of the phones that would support a J2ME Midlet application given all the JSR's it uses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

J2ME is heavily dependent on the implementation of the VM by the phone vendors. There are many functions that are interpreted in other ways by each vendor, or on each phone etc.

You can only test on as many different phones, with many different vendors, different specifications etc.

It depends not only on the JSR's you are using it also depends on the memory you are using the GUI functions you try to use etc. This can give you a serious headache but I don't know of another way then simply testing on real devices as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second all Janusz comments on the issue.

However, some resources to help you:

[WFURL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)
[JBenchmark](http://www.jbenchmark.com/)

Both of these collect mobile phone information that could prove useful.